# R calculates wrong?

Tags: r, calculation

How can that be?

```
> mode(daten[1,16])
[1] "numeric"
> mode(weku)
[1] "numeric"
>
> weku
[1] 10.47855
> daten[1,16]
[1] 814995955
> daten[1,16]/weku
[1] 77777557
>
> 814995955/10.47855
[1] 77777551
>
```

I don't understand this. How can I get the correct calculation?

Comment: `sprintf("%f16",weku)`?

Comment: Try `format(weku, 10)`. I presume it is not exactly 10.47855 but rather that's how many digits were displayed.

Comment: I'd bet `sprintf("%s", weku)` prints `[1] "10.4785491"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`daten[1,16]/weku` is correct.

R does not display all of the decimal values it stores internally. What is printed on the console is controlled by `options("digits")`.

For example, compare `print(pi)`, `print(pi, digits=10)`, and `print(pi, digits=22)`.